# Conditional mutate map lm within a nested data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

I am trying to run a stratified analysis fitting a slightly different model in a particular strata using a nested data.frame and map mutate approach:

```
cars_nest <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  nest()

model1 <- function(df) {
  lm(mpg ~ disp + wt, data = df)
}

model2 <- function(df) {
  lm(mpg ~ disp + wt + factor(vs), data = df)
}

cars_nest %>% 
  mutate(
    model = case_when(
      cyl == 8 ~ map(data, model1),
      cyl %in% c(4, 6) ~ map(data, model2)
    )
  )
```

I'm getting the error

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `model`.
> x contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
> ℹ Input `model` is `case_when(...)`.
> ℹ The error occurred in group 3: cyl = 8.

I assume this is due to the vectorized operation of case_when as the below does seem to work.

```
cars_nest %>% 
  mutate(
    model = ifelse(cyl == 8, map(data, model1),
                   ifelse(cyl %in% c(4, 6), map(data, model2), NA)
    )
  )
```

Is there a way to make this work using case_when()?

**NOTE:** the factor in model2 is necessary to replicate the issue. in the actual model, this is a factor that has only one level in the first strata and more than one level in the second strata.

Comment: It is related to your model2

Answer (score 2):

We could use `if/else`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
   nest_by(cyl) %>% 
   mutate(model = if(cur_group() == 8) list(model1(data)) else 
              list(model2(data))) %>% 
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    cyl           data model   
#  <dbl> <list<tibble>> <list>
#1     4      [11 × 10] <lm>  
#2     6       [7 × 10] <lm>  
#3     8      [14 × 10] <lm>
```

---

Or using the OP's code

```
library(purrr)
cars_nest %>% 
  mutate(
    model = 
      if(cur_group() == 8) map(data, model1)
      else map(data, model2)
    )
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [3]
#    cyl data               model 
#  <dbl> <list>             <list>
#1     6 <tibble [7 × 10]>  <lm>  
#2     4 <tibble [11 × 10]> <lm>  
#3     8 <tibble [14 × 10]> <lm>
```

---

Comment: Yes, I note this in the original question. Hoping to find a way to leverage the case_when syntax.

Comment: @RaoulDuke with `case_when`, the default option is NA and there is a type check and structure check

Comment: @RaoulDuke Besides, I would never use `case_when` when the input logic vector is of length 1.  `ifelse` or `case_when` are used when you have more than one length.  May be you can ungroup and then apply `case_when`, but again it is a bit more tricky as it does type check and length check for all arguments

Comment: Dear Arun, first I was thinking about iterating on 2 variables but I just couldn't figure out why this doesn't work: `cars_nest %>%
  mutate(model = map2(cyl, data, ~ ifelse(.x %in% c(4, 6), model2(.y), model1(.y))))`

Comment: It apparently results in a nested listed of depth 2 but the underlying value is not of `lm` class.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR it is a nested list, but I get the lm results there if you pull the model  `cars_nest %>%   mutate(model = map2(cyl, data, ~ ifelse(.x %in% c(4, 6), model2(.y), model1(.y)))) %>% pull(model)`

Comment: @akrun I got it, thank you very much indeed.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR sometimes I miss the comments when I am working on server and then forget to reply. Sorry

Comment: @akrun Oh it's totally ok, I understand. As a matter of fact you don't have to reply to any comment or question because we are all have our preoccupations and I don't expect a quick response. I totally understand your situation and I am already in your debt & grateful for all the things you taught me. Just take your time whenever it was possible for you.

Comment: @akrun and again I am so sorry to ask so many questions. I hope I can return the favor one day.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following solution, however there is not much difference between all these:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)

cars_nest %>%
  mutate(model = ifelse(cyl %in% c(4, 6), map(data, ~ model2(.)), 
                        map(data, ~ model1(.))), 
         glance = map(model, ~ glance(.x))) %>%
  unnest(glance) %>%
  select(-data)

# A tibble: 3 x 14
# Groups:   cyl [3]
    cyl model r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC deviance
  <dbl> <lis>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1     6 <lm>      0.702         0.403  1.12      2.35  0.251      3  -7.78  25.6  25.3     3.78
2     4 <lm>      0.659         0.513  3.15      4.51  0.0461     3 -25.7   61.5  63.5    69.3 
3     8 <lm>      0.425         0.320  2.11      4.06  0.0477     2 -28.6   65.3  67.8    49.0 
# ... with 2 more variables: df.residual <int>, nobs <int>
```

Comment: As dear @akrun just mentioned, I personally never use `case_when` when I can use `ifelse` or `if_else` as they are more flexible. However it's a personal choice and this is just my opinion.

Comment: `if_else` would also some type check.  `case_when` or `if_else` are good options.  It is just that when the objects to return here is complex and our logicall condition length is for a single row

Comment: @akrun you are absolutely right. I just need to experience more options with them. I just could not find out what was going wrong with that `map2` option.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove `factor` from `model2`:

```
model2 <- function(df) {
  lm(mpg ~ disp + wt + vs, data = df)
}
```

Then

```
cars_nest %>% 
  mutate(
    model = case_when(
      cyl == 8 ~ map(data, model1),
      cyl %in% c(4, 6) ~ map(data, model2)
    )
  ) %>% 
  print
```

results in

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [3]
    cyl data                    model 
  <dbl> <list>                  <list>
1     6 <tibble[,10] [7 x 10]>  <lm>  
2     4 <tibble[,10] [11 x 10]> <lm>  
3     8 <tibble[,10] [14 x 10]> <lm>
```

Comment: the factor statement is necessary to reproduce the conditions of the issue (see edit)

Comment: I hadn't realized that you used `factor` on purpose to create the error. Perhaps this should have been explained in the original post.